# Pivot a query SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server

Tengo un query en sql server 2014 que me da este resultado:

```html
select sum(V.Ventas) as Ventas, V.Mes, V.Dia 
 from( select V.Usuario, count(V.IdVenta) as Ventas,V.Año, V.Mes, V.Semana, V.Dia, V.Fecha
 from( select V.Usuario, V.IdVenta, P.Descripcion, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),V.Fecha,23) AS Fecha, DATENAME(year, V.Fecha) as Año, DATENAME(month, V.Fecha) as Mes, S.Semana, DATENAME(day, V.Fecha) as Dia 
 from VentasT V 
 left join ClientesV C on V.IdVenta=C.IdVenta 
 left join Ventas P ON V.IdVenta= P.IdVenta 
 LEFT join CatSemanas S ON V.Fecha between S.Inicio and S.Fin 
 GROUP BY  V.Usuario, V.IdVenta, V.Año, V.Mes, V.Semana, V.Dia, V.Fecha)V 
 where V.Usuario= 4 
 GROUP BY V.Fecha, V.Año, V.Mes, V.Dia 
 order by V.Fecha
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora lo que necesito es mostrarlo en un una tabla en asp .net (uso c#) pero acomodando los datos de esta manera:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Intente asi pero se repite el mes

```html
 select Mes, [1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[11],[12],[13],[14],[15],[16],[17],[18],[19],[20],[21],[22],[23],[24],[25],[26],[27],[28],[29],[30],[31] 
 from( 
 select sum(V.Ventas) as Ventas, V.Mes, V.Dia 
 from( 
 select V.Usuario, count(V.IdVenta) as Ventas,V.Año, V.Mes,    V.Semana, V.Dia, V.Fecha
 from( select V.Usuario, V.IdVenta, P.Descripcion, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),V.Fecha,23) AS Fecha, DATENAME(year, V.Fecha) as Año, DATENAME(month, V.Fecha) as Mes, S.Semana, DATENAME(day, V.Fecha) as Dia 
 from VentasT V 
 left join ClientesV C on V.IdVenta=C.IdVenta 
 left join Ventas P ON V.IdVenta= P.IdVenta 
 LEFT join CatSemanas S ON V.Fecha between S.Inicio and S.Fin 
 GROUP BY  V.Usuario, V.IdVenta, V.Año, V.Mes, V.Semana, V.Dia,     V.Fecha)V 
 )V 
 GROUP BY  V.Usuario, V.IdVenta, V.Año, V.Mes, V.Semana, V.Dia, V.Fecha
 )V  
 pivot (sum(Ventas) FOR Dia in([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[11],[12],[13],[14],[15],[16],[17],[18],[19],[20],[21],[22],[23],[24],[25],[26],[27],[28],[29],[30],[31]) ) as P
  where Usuario= 4 
  order by Fecha
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Haz el query en sql usando la funcion [PIVOT ](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms177410(v=sql.105)) para que te monte las filas y columnas que necesitas, luego esa tabla la pasas como datasource al gridview, lo demas ya es cuestion de estilos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aquí hay una alternativa a PIVOT que es más flexible. Usé un CTE para *pre-agregar* los datos antes de convertir las filas en columnas. También reduje en número de pasos que tenías en subconsultas, ya que parecían innecesarios.

```
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT  DATENAME(year, V.Fecha) as Año, 
            DATENAME(month, V.Fecha) as Mes, 
            DATENAME(day, V.Fecha) AS Dia,
            COUNT( *) AS Ventas
    FROM VentasT V 
    LEFT JOIN ClientesV C on V.IdVenta=C.IdVenta 
    LEFT JOIN Ventas P ON V.IdVenta= P.IdVenta 
    LEFT JOIN CatSemanas S ON V.Fecha between S.Inicio and S.Fin 
    WHERE Usuario= 4 
    GROUP BY DATENAME(year, V.Fecha),
            DATENAME(month, V.Fecha),
            DATENAME(day, V.Fecha)
)
SELECT  Año, 
        Mes, 
        SUM( CASE WHEN Dia =  1 THEN Ventas END) as [1], 
        SUM( CASE WHEN Dia =  2 THEN Ventas END) as [2], 
        SUM( CASE WHEN Dia =  3 THEN Ventas END) as [3], 
        SUM( CASE WHEN Dia =  4 THEN Ventas END) as [4], 
        SUM( CASE WHEN Dia =  5 THEN Ventas END) as [5], 
        SUM( CASE WHEN Dia =  6 THEN Ventas END) as [6], 
        SUM( CASE WHEN Dia =  7 THEN Ventas END) as [7], 
        SUM( CASE WHEN Dia =  8 THEN Ventas END) as [8], 
        SUM( CASE WHEN Dia =  9 THEN Ventas END) as [9], 
        SUM( CASE WHEN Dia = 10 THEN Ventas END) as [10], 
        SUM( CASE WHEN Dia = 11 THEN Ventas END) as [11], 
        SUM( CASE WHEN Dia = 12 THEN Ventas END) as [12], 
        SUM( CASE WHEN Dia = 13 THEN Ventas END) as [13], 
        SUM( CASE WHEN Dia = 14 THEN Ventas END) as [14], 
        SUM( CASE WHEN Dia = 15 THEN Ventas END) as [15], 
        SUM( CASE WHEN Dia = 16 THEN Ventas END) as [16], 
        SUM( CASE WHEN Dia = 17 THEN Ventas END) as [17], 
        SUM( CASE WHEN Dia = 18 THEN Ventas END) as [18], 
        SUM( CASE WHEN Dia = 19 THEN Ventas END) as [19], 
        SUM( CASE WHEN Dia = 20 THEN Ventas END) as [20], 
        SUM( CASE WHEN Dia = 21 THEN Ventas END) as [21], 
        SUM( CASE WHEN Dia = 22 THEN Ventas END) as [22], 
        SUM( CASE WHEN Dia = 23 THEN Ventas END) as [23], 
        SUM( CASE WHEN Dia = 24 THEN Ventas END) as [24], 
        SUM( CASE WHEN Dia = 25 THEN Ventas END) as [25], 
        SUM( CASE WHEN Dia = 26 THEN Ventas END) as [26], 
        SUM( CASE WHEN Dia = 27 THEN Ventas END) as [27], 
        SUM( CASE WHEN Dia = 28 THEN Ventas END) as [28], 
        SUM( CASE WHEN Dia = 29 THEN Ventas END) as [29], 
        SUM( CASE WHEN Dia = 30 THEN Ventas END) as [30], 
        SUM( CASE WHEN Dia = 31 THEN Ventas END) as [31]
FROM CTE
GROUP BY Año, Mes;
```